# Is there a way to use the OSX cocoa NSApplication method activateIgnoringOtherApps: to activate an app that is already loading

Tags: cocoa, macos, activation

This may be a dumb question but it seems like activateIgnoringOtherApps: may be the only way to activate an app using Cocoa.  I have a java app that loads up a Cocoa app and I want the Cocoa app to be activated when this happens.  The problem is I do not want to have to launch an intermediate app (some sort of controller) and use this app to activateIgnoringOtherApps: my other Cocoa app.  Is there some way to use activateIgnoringOtherApps: to force my Cocoa app to become active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not understanding how it works. This is a method that would be called from within the application to make it become the active application. You can't send this message to another application that isn't running to make it start.